# Ionic 3: Pushing a page on specified tab

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

#### The situation

I am creating an app consisting of a root page containing `<ion-tabs>` with each tab page being a "master page" of a master-detail-pattern (see diagram below).

[Diagram of my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvV4p.png)

#### My goal

Now, I am trying to get directly to a Detail page from my `TabsPage`, as I have a FAB in my *tabbar* opening a QR-Code-Scanner from which the result should lead to the detail page (based on the id one has scanned).

#### What I have already tried

I have tried several ways and the best solution **(still not working as expected, though)** was using

```
let navCtrl: NavController = this.app.getRootNav();
nav.push(DetailPageA, { id: scannedId });
```

in my `tabs.ts` file.

Unfortunately, with this method, it pushes the Detail page "over" the `TabsPage`, thus hiding the *tabbar*.

#### My Question:

**Is it possible to push to a detail page "into" a tab (from "outside" the tab) with the result being the same as going there "manually" through the master page (i.e. keeping the *tabbar* visible and having `navCtrl.pop()` on the detail page lead "back" to the master page)?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: from where you need to push to detail page ? r u on First tab first screen ?

Comment: @CodeChanger That's not defined: As the FAB is displayed within the *tabbar*, it can be reached from any "subpage" of the tabs. This is why I suspect I have to programmatically go to the root of the first tab and push the page after that. But so far, I have no luck getting that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Import `App` in the page from where you want to open Details Page

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
```

then use below code to push your desired page in tabs:-

```
this.app.getActiveNav().push(DetailPageA);
```

Comment: So did you achieved your goal??